# How to read the header content of a webpage in Django?

Tags: python, django, http-headers

I created a search engine in Django and bs4 that scrapes search results from the [Ask.com](https://Ask.com) search engine. I would like when Django fetches search results from Ask, it checks the value of the X-Frame-Options header in order to give a value to my `notAccept` boolean depending on the result of the condition.

I took inspiration from [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers) of the Django documentation and also from [this other page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and after testing a proposed answer, I modified my code like this:

```
for result in result_listings:
                result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
                result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
                result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text

                res = requests.get(result_url)
              

                #for header in final_result[1]:
                response = res.headers['content-type':'X-Frame-Options'] #the error is generated here
                if response in ["DENY", "SAMEORIGIN"]:
                    head = True
                    notAccept = bool(head)
```

But when I test, I get in the terminal the following errors:

```
    Internal Server Error: /search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\searchEngine\search\views.py", line 32, in search
    response = res.headers['content-type':'X-Frame-Options']
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'lower'
[26/Sep/2022 22:57:24] "GET /search?csrfmiddlewaretoken=1m8mRf9JWoHvzps2AemMyA7Wlb76PVzQ5UzuEtfH1p3PzwmZfqLlBHTkCvIDlot6&search=moto HTTP/1.1" 500 93598
```

This error is related to the following line as specified in the code.

```
response = res.headers['content-type':'X-Frame-Options'] #the error is generated here
```

I modified this line like this:

```
response = res.headers['X-Frame-Options']
```

but now I obtain the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\AAprojects\Whelpsgroups1\searchEngine\search\views.py", line 32, in search
    response = res.headers['X-Frame-Options'] #the error is generated here
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'x-frame-options'
```

I looked on [this page](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find a solution but I can't find much.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I'm not very good with handling headers I must admit. Thank you!

Comment: I don't undestand where you search these values. You should search in `res.headers`

Comment: in Python `if` uses `or` instead of `|`, `and` instead of `&`, `not` instead of `!`

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you may get message about `(` if you have different number of `(` and `)`

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Python Requests issue than Django.. from my limited knowledge I don't believe you **can** get header information of pages just by looking at the Links. You need to actually send a GET request because it's in the Header of the request:

```py
for l in links:
    response = requests.get(l)
    if response['X-Frame-Options'] in ["DENY", "SAMEORIGIN"]:
        head = True
        notAccept = bool(head)
    else:
        notAccept = bool(False)
```

I was unable to find **anything** about `CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS` tho..

Hopefully you can find some of this useful.. at the very least now you know to search `python requests {x}` on the topic

---

#### Edit

I'll explain the error that you've added, invalid Index:

```py
# Final Result is an Array Filled with Tuples
#   OR just think of it as an Array filled with Arrays
# ---

# This would be the result on the first loop:

final_result = [
    (result_title0, result_url0, result_desc0), # index 0
    ]

# You used:
final_result[1] # => Undefined

# Correct Way:
# ---

# Grab first item in Array:
final_result[0] # => (result_title0, result_url0, result_desc0)

# Grab first item in Array + and then 2nd item in list:
final_result[0][1] # => result_url0

# Next Issue
# ---

# But you will run into this issue / always grabbing the first item
final_result = [
    (result_title0, result_url0, result_desc0), # index 0
    (result_title1, result_url1, result_desc1), # index 1
    ]


final_result[0][1] # => result_url0 **Wrong!**

# -1 should be used instead // (Last Item in list)
final_result[-1][1] # => result_url1 **Correct!**

# ^ Actual solution
# ---
```

But because you already have `result_url` as a variable in the loop you might has well use it in the GET instead of trying to fetch it from that Nested Array

```py
for result in result_listings:
    result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
    result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
    result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text
    final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc))

    # Ping URL found here: result.find('a').get('href')
    response = requests.get(result_url)

    # Check for header information in the response
    if response['X-Frame-Options'] in ["DENY", "SAMEORIGIN"]:
        # head = True
        notAccept = True
    else:
        notAccept = False
```

and you might as well wait until the very end to add that tuple to the final_result list- maybe even use a dictonary

##### Wait until end

```py
for result in result_listings:
    result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
    result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
    result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text

    # Ping URL found here: result.find('a').get('href')
    response = requests.get(result_url)

    # Check for header information in the response
    if response['X-Frame-Options'] in ["DENY", "SAMEORIGIN"]:
        # head = True
        notAccept = True
    else:
        notAccept = False

    # Add here! Last second.
    final_result.append((result_title, result_url, result_desc, notAccept))
```

##### Wait until end + Dict

```py
for result in result_listings:
    result_title = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-title').text
    result_url = result.find('a').get('href')
    result_desc = result.find(class_='PartialSearchResults-item-abstract').text

    # Ping URL found here: result.find('a').get('href')
    response = requests.get(result_url)

    # Check for header information in the response
    if response['X-Frame-Options'] in ["DENY", "SAMEORIGIN"]:
        # head = True
        notAccept = True
    else:
        notAccept = False

    # Dict makes Code a little more readable last on when you use this data
    final_result.append({
        'title':result_title,
        'url': result_url,
        'desc': result_desc,
        'x-frame': notAccept
        })
```

---

#### Edit 2

So the error you are getting `KeyError: 'x-frame-options'` and that means `x-frame-options` isn't in the header.

The `res.header` is a dictionary like:

- do `print(res.header)` and you can see it yourself.

```py
res.header = {
    'content-encoding': 'gzip',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    'connection': 'close',
    'server': 'nginx/1.0.4',
    'x-runtime': '148ms',
    'etag': '"e1ca502697e5c9317743dc078f67693f"',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

## Your error, an explanation:

print(res.header.keys()) 
# ['content-encoding' 'transfer-encoding', 'connection', 'server', 'x-runtime', 'etag', 'content-type',]


print('x-frame-options' in re.header.keys())
# False

res.header['x-frame-options']
# KeyError: Key doesn't exist!
```

> If you try to fetch a Key that isn't in the Dictionary, you'll get a KeyError

##### Here's some Potential things you can do: (it depends on your end goal)

###### 1, see if x-frame-options is in header (Return True or False)

```py
has_x_frame_options = ('x-frame-options' in res.header.keys())

print(type(has_x_frame_options), has_x_frame_options)
# Bool, (True or False)
```

###### 2, get Value of x-frame-options **if** it's in the header, *else* be false

```py
if 'x-frame-options' in res.header.keys():
    x_frame_options = res.header['x-frame-options']
else:
    x_frame_options = False

print(type(x_frame_options), x_frame_options)
# will be: 
#    String, '{some_string}'
#    Bool, False

# Condensed like:
x_frame_options = res.header['x-frame-options'] if 'x-frame-options' in res.header.keys() else False
```

Comment: I tested your solution but I have a problem. More details in my question. Thanks !

Comment: I've added an edit for that error you had. I also explained that next error you'd come across- so make sure you reach the bottom in that code block!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had a few issues to sort out. Thanks for the solution, it helped me solve my problem with the loop but I still get an error. I've detailed the error more in my edited question and want to clarify that my code has changed. Thank you again and have a nice day!

Comment: the `:` in `res.headers['content-type':'X-Frame-Options']` is invalid. You can't grab two keys like that in a dictionary, it's either `response = res.headers['content-type']` or `response = res.headers['X-Frame-Options']` ..you could do something like this: `content_type, x_frame_options = res.headers['content-type'], res.headers['X-Frame-Options']`, but it's going to have to be two vars

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I modified this line of code from this comment; but I still get an error at the same line, I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean. Can you give me a sample code please? Thanks!

Comment: I've added an edit explaining the error and 2 potential solutions, sorta just depends on your end goal which one to use- if all you care about is if the key is in the header do #1, else do #2

Comment: You made a spelling error, it's `headers` not `header`.

Comment: meh you got the point tho. did that work?

Comment: It doesn't work but I am testing a solution from your answer code, I will let you know if it works or not.